# php foreach form dropdown menu with selected tag

Tags: php, loops, drop-down-menu, foreach, selectedindex

Guys I have a dropdown list which, when i press the button, i want to mark the selected row automatically! my code so far is shown below, but i cant get it work... with `'` `"` etc.

```
echo "<select id='form' name=form style='width:auto' class='form-control'>
<optgroup label='form_name'>";

foreach($results as $result)                                    
{
    $ID      = $result->ID;
    $name    = $result->name;
    $address = $result->address;

    echo '<option value=$ID '. 

    **if(isset($_GET['form']) &&  $_GET['form'] == $ID ){  .' selected="selected" '. } else { .''. }**                               

    .'>'.$ID. ". " .$name. " [" .$address.']</option>'; 

}                               
echo "</optgroup>
</select>;
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should use " " quotation for $ID to be used `"<option value=$ID "`

Comment: `"<select id='form' name=form style='width:auto'` you have to put name in quotation marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your code in this way:

```
echo "<select id='form' name=form style='width:auto' class='form-control'>
    <optgroup label='form_name'>";
    foreach($results as $result)                                    
    {
        $ID      = $result->ID;
        $name    = $result->name;
        $address = $result->address;

        $selected = ( isset($_GET['form']) &&  $_GET['form'] == $ID ) ? ' selected="selected" ' : '';

        echo '<option value=$ID '
                . $selected
                .'>'.$ID. ". " .$name. " [" .$address.']</option>'; 
    }                               
echo " </optgroup>
           </select>;
```

Comment: they were both the same answer i presume!!

Comment: @ΗλιαςΤσορομωκος correct, we answered simultaneously, so I sow the other user's answer after posting mine, otherwise I will not answer ;)

Comment: i'll give the bonus to this answer because it's more tidy from the other but plz no hard feelings ok?! thank you both of you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator.
The ternary operator is a simple "if then else" in just one line.

```
echo '<select id="form" name="form" style="width:auto" class="form-control">';
    echo '<optgroup label="form_name">';

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $id      = $result->ID;
        $name    = $result->name;
        $address = $result->address;

        echo '<option value="' . $id . '" ' . (isset($_GET['form']) && $_GET['form'] == $id ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $id . '. ' . $name . ' [' . $address . ']</option>';
    }

    echo '</optgroup>';
echo '</select>';
```